# Parallelize a task on gpu

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, gpu

I have a task in which I have to read in some images, perform some trasformations such as resizing the images, etc, and then write the image back on the disk. I can parallelize this operation over my cpu. However, I was wondering if there is a possible way to parallelize this over gpu. Since, this would make my task terminate quicker.

I should specify that the images that I have are quiet large. Their size tends to be around 5000px X 4000px.

I perform this task in python 3.

So I would like to know if this is even possible. If yes, where can I begin from?

Comment: Pretty sure you could explore the machine learning libraries such as pytorch/tensorflow and leverage their API to parallelize your image processing jobs. Otherwise you will have to look at the python CUDA library.

Comment: Consider checking OpenCV. This is a famous library for fast image transformations/recognition/computer-vision. It provides a support for GPUs. It is available from Python. Note that opening/saving the image from/to the disk is dependent of the target file format and some cannot be efficiently handled on GPUs (like PNG files that making use of the deflate algorithm). The resizing operation should scale very well on a GPU (which are quite design for such a task).